# Custom font not working after updating appcompat library to 23.4.0.1

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, custom-font, android-appcompat

I have been using a custom font for all the views in my application. But currently the font is getting applied only for the toolbar while the rest of the views uses the default font. This occured in side effect toa appcompat lib update to version 23.4.0.1. Has any one experienced this issue. Please find below the font usage classes

**FontUtility.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace HPScanJA.Android.Utils
{
    class FontUtility
    {
        public static Typeface applyRegularFont(Context context)
        {

            Typeface hpRegularTypeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "fonts/Simplified_Rg.ttf");
            return hpRegularTypeface;
        }

        public static Typeface applyBoldFont(Context context)
        {

            Typeface hpBoldTypeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "fonts/Simplified_Bd.ttf");
            return hpBoldTypeface;
        }
    }
}
```

also the usage is in the base activity shown below. This gets extended by all the activities

**BaseActivity.cs**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;
using HPScanJA.Android.Utils;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

namespace HPScanJA.Android.Activities
{
    [Activity(Label = "BaseActivity")]
    public class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        Context context;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            context = this;
            // Get the Resources object from our context
            global::Android.Content.Res.Resources res = context.Resources;

            // Create your application here
            int titleId = res.GetIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id",
                "android");
            TextView titleView = (TextView)FindViewById(titleId);
            if (titleView != null)
                titleView.SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyRegularFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(string name, Context context, global::Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs)
        {
            View view = base.OnCreateView(name, context, attrs);
            return setCustomTypeFaceIfNeeded(name, attrs, view);
        }


        protected View setCustomTypeFaceIfNeeded(String name, global::Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs, View view)
        {
            View result = null;
            Console.WriteLine("*******************************************"+name+"*******************************************");
            if ("TextView".Equals(name))
            {
                result = new TextView(this, attrs);

                if (null != ((TextView)result).Typeface && TypefaceStyle.Bold == ((TextView)result).Typeface.Style)
                {
                    ((TextView)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyBoldFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((TextView)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyRegularFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }


            }

            else if ("EditText".Equals(name))
            {
                result = new EditText(this, attrs);
                if (null != ((EditText)result).Typeface && TypefaceStyle.Bold == ((EditText)result).Typeface.Style)
                {
                    ((EditText)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyBoldFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((EditText)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyRegularFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }

            }

            else if ("Button".Equals(name))
            {
                result = new Button(this, attrs);
                if (null != ((Button)result).Typeface && TypefaceStyle.Bold == ((Button)result).Typeface.Style)
                {
                    ((Button)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyBoldFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((Button)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyRegularFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }

            }

            else if ("CheckedTextView".Equals(name))
            {
                result = new CheckedTextView(this, attrs);
                if (null != ((CheckedTextView)result).Typeface && TypefaceStyle.Bold == ((CheckedTextView)result).Typeface.Style)
                {
                    ((CheckedTextView)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyBoldFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((CheckedTextView)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyRegularFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }

            }

            else if ("CheckBox".Equals(name))
            {
                result = new CheckBox(this, attrs);
                if (null != ((CheckBox)result).Typeface && TypefaceStyle.Bold == ((CheckBox)result).Typeface.Style)
                {
                    ((CheckBox)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyBoldFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((CheckBox)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyRegularFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }

            }
            else if ("RadioButton".Equals(name))
            {
                result = new RadioButton(this, attrs);
                if (null != ((RadioButton)result).Typeface && TypefaceStyle.Bold == ((RadioButton)result).Typeface.Style)
                {
                    ((RadioButton)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyBoldFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((RadioButton)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyRegularFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }

            }
            else if ("Switch".Equals(name))
            {
                result = new Switch(this, attrs);
                if (null != ((Switch)result).Typeface && TypefaceStyle.Bold == ((Switch)result).Typeface.Style)
                {
                    ((Switch)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyBoldFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((Switch)result).SetTypeface(FontUtility.applyRegularFont(context), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }

            }




            if (result == null)
            {
                return view;
            }
            else
            {
                return result;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Kindly let me know if anyone faced this issue.

Comment: what is this: 23.4.0.1, this is not possible..  just use 23.4.0 only.. remove 1

Comment: this is the updated version of the android support library. Also it is not something which I added at the end. The version number came up along with the update

Comment: but latest updated library is 24.1.1.. you can find it here..  http://gradleplease.appspot.com/, they are showing right now a stable version.. nd always use stable version for project

Comment: yes I know of that but this issue I happen to stumble upon being reported in code.google.com as an issue of appcompat I dont think it is regarding the 23rd release alone. Also my .Visual Studio has notified only about the 23.4.0.1. If I need to update to 24 I will have to do a manual download

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170476 check this link.

Comment: but you can change it manually.. just use any other stable version like 23.3.0..

Comment: Also for Xamarin.Android the latest seem to be 23.4.0.1  check this link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long while finally I solved this...
This issue was occurring as the BaseActivity class is trying to change the font during run time. Prior to support library v23 this was working fine. But from support lib v23 onward the system was changing certain view types during run time and hence this piece of code was not working.

I solved this by going with a different approach that is to extend each UI View class and set the typeface within it 
 For eg. the Textviews code is given below

```
 public class CustomTextView : TextView
{
    public CustomTextView(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        SetCustomTypeFace();
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {

        SetCustomTypeFace();

    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
        SetCustomTypeFace();
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
        SetCustomTypeFace();

    }

    public void SetCustomTypeFace()
    {
        Typeface tf = null;
        if (this.Typeface.Style == TypefaceStyle.Normal)
        {
            tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, "fonts/Simplified_Rg.ttf");
        }
        else if (this.Typeface.Style == TypefaceStyle.Bold)
        {
            tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, "fonts/Simplified_Bd.ttf");

        }
        SetTypeface(tf, this.Typeface.Style);
    }

}
```

Then I used this custom textview in the layout instead of the default TextView.